# How does Password generator includes every parts of string

Tags: python, random

I want to make password generator but I have a little problem. I want a password which included uppercase+lowercase+number+specialchar. Sometimes it works, it incluedes everything but sometimes it doesn't.

Here's my code

```
import random

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

lchar4pass = alphabet
uchar4pass = alphabet.upper()
numb4pass = "0123456789"
schar4pass = "()_-+[]{;}/.,!@$%#&*"


passlen = 0

while True:
    try:
        passlen = int(input("Enter the lenght of passw0rd: "))
    except:
        print("\nYou can't use a letter or a word for length.")
    if passlen > 11 and passlen < 83:
        break
    else:
        print("\nEnter a number between 11 and 83.\n")


passw0rd = lchar4pass + uchar4pass + numb4pass + schar4pass


passw0rd = "".join(random.sample(passw0rd,passlen))


print(passw0rd)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should first choose one character of each group to ensure your criteria, and then `sample` the remaining `passlen-4` characters

Comment: just fyi: you probably want to `import string` and use `string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_uppercase, string.ponctuation, string.digits`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided code you are generating the string from all characters and then randomly selecting chars from there, there is a possibility that generated passwords will not include chars from all categories.

What I'm suggesting is to keep a string of each category separated and choose randomly from them.

You are free to choose the count of chars from each category.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I can do that then use random.sample func to turn much complex password. Thanks Farhad!